# Nested mapping in hibernate

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, nhibernate-mapping

I have User, Report and Feedback classes and I want to fetch all three tables data at once but I am not getting Feedback class data. Is this a right way or there any other way to do it?

User.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private int id;

    //other variables

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Profile profile;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Report> result;
}
```

Report.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "report")
public class Report {

    @Id
    private int id;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH}, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private User user;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "report",cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Feedback feedback;
}
```

Feedback.java

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name="feedback")
    public class Feedback {
    
        @Id
        private int id;
        private int user_id;
        private int report_id;
    
        @JsonIgnore
        @OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.PERSIST,
                CascadeType.DETACH,CascadeType.REFRESH},fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumn(name="report_id")
        private Report report;
}
```

Controller.java

```
  @RequestMapping("/all/report")
    public @ResponseBody
    List<User> showReport() {
        List<User> userList=userDAO.findAll();
        return userList;
    }
```

Here is the List.

```
{
    "id": 290,
    "profile": {
     //profile data
    },
    "result": [
      {
        //result data
      }
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a JPQL query for this purpose like below:

```java
@Query("select distinct u from User u join fetch u.result r join fetch r.feedback")
List<User> fetchAllUsersWithReportsAndFeedback();
```

Comment: Now I am getting single row of each table. Report table has one to many relationship with user table but showing only one record. I have removed distinct keyword still not working.